# Detecting line sinuosity using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a working code [from an old SE post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256622/adding-line-sinuosity-with-pyqgis) to detect line sinuosity using field calculator as shown here:

[image: Sinuosity]

```
processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator',
                  {"INPUT": '',
                   "FIELD_NAME": "sinuosity",
                   "FIELD_TYPE": 0,
                   "FORMULA": 'length($geometry)/distance(start_point($geometry), end_point( $geometry))',
                   "NEW_FIELD": True,
                   "OUTPUT": '})
```

This works in the image above where 1 = straight and all anything higher or lower denotes curves.

When I run this on a larger dataset with connected pieces (CRS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic), I get mixed results as shown in this image with the straight highlighted line having a value of 32.76 and others having varying values:

[image: Sinuosity2]

I have tried converting the line strings from multipart to single part but that does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Which Coordinate Reference System does your data have?

Comment: Since you said that using single parts didn't solve the issue, you can look at the vertices order for this particular segment

Comment: CRS: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic

Comment: Vertices: when I extract vertices, this segment has 18. unsure of how to check the order

Comment: use the [vertex tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#vertex-tool)

Comment: The order looks correct but there are a handful of overlapping vertices

Comment: Please provide a link to the old SO post.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256622/adding-line-sinuosity-with-pyqgis

Comment: please add extra information to your question by editing it, rather than in the comments where it is harder to find.