# Remove unwanted vertices from a straight line

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, line

I have a MultiLine String that is straight but when I highlight vertices, I notice that it has 10 vertices - some vertices also overlap. When I covert this multipart line to singlepart, the line still has 10 vertices.

I would like to simplify this line (which has one single id) to have only one a start and end point.

I have tried dissolving the line, fix geometry and simplify and can't seem to remove the unwanted vertices

[image: Line]
[image: Vertices]

Comment: You only have one line?

Comment: this is just a subset for an example of a larger dataset

Comment: Can you post a new image with the vertices numbered by their order?  There are some results returned from the Plugins manager if you search on Topology but I do not have experience with these.   Of course, if all else fails there is a Python solution.  Maybe   extract the vertices from the lines, generate minimum enclosing circles around the vertices, select the vertices that intersect the circle and rebuild the lines.

Comment: Is it actually a single LineString, or a series of LineStrings, as in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/423454/128665). If it is the former, please include details about parameter settings of the methods you tried. For instance, what was the Simplification method and Tolerance in Simplify?

Comment: It is a single LineString. I have tried dissolve by ID and simplify with a tolerance of .001 in meters. The issue with going any higher for tolerance is that this is part of a much larger dataset and I do not want to simplify other geometries to a great extent. I am  trying to detect straight lines related to this post and believe that the vertices are causing issues: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424762/detecting-line-sinuosity-with-pyqgis?noredirect=1#comment692903_424762

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following expression to eliminate all vertices from a line that deviate for a maximum distance from the direct line connecting the start- and end-point of a line. Use [Geoemtry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

- The expression evaluates for each vertex of the initial line, except for start- and end-point, if a buffer of distance `x` (here: `50` on line 20, change this value to fit your needs) intersects the direct line connecting start- and end-point.
- If so, the output is an empty element, otherwise the output is the respective vertex as a point geometry.
- So for each vertex, these outputs are collected in an array and then the array is filtered to retain only elements > 0. You get an array than only contains points.
- These ponints represent the vertices further away from the line connecting start- and end-point than the distance you defined.
- Add start- and end-point of the initial line at the beginning and end of the array and convert the array to a line and here you are!

```
make_line (
    array (
        start_point ($geometry),
        collect_geometries (
            array_filter (
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series (2, num_points( $geometry)-1),
                    case
                    when        
                        intersects (
                            make_line (
                                start_point ($geometry), 
                                end_point ($geometry)
                            ),
                            buffer (
                                point_n (
                                    $geometry, 
                                    @element
                                ), 
                                1  -- change this distance
                            )
                        ) = 0
                    then point_n ($geometry, @element)
                    end
                ),
                @element>0
            )
        ), 
        end_point ($geometry)
    )
)
```

*Black line with initial vertices (red dots) as well as the vertices of the line created by the expression above in blue (adding a `nodes_to_points()` function to the expression) - as you can see, just 2 vertices (start- and end-point) remain:*
[image]